# Primefaces selectOneMenu with Selenium webdriver does not select the item + Java

Tags: java, firefox, testing, selenium, primefaces

I need to set value on p:selectOneMenu during my selenium test but having problem to set the value.
here is the code i used to do that:

```
{
driver.findElement(By.id("myForm:meSelection_label")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='myForm:meSelection_panel']/div[2]/ul/li[text() = 'mytext']")).click();
}
```

Problem is that it does not select my selection, i even tried to use index on li (e.g. /li[2]) it is second item.
when i run the test it shows the dropdown list and i can see my elements in it but it just do not select the element. And yes, i do have converter on for this object.
I also tried Selenium IDE and put my xpath in there exactly the same as above and it works perfectly fine, but in my test case in java it does not select the element at all.

I searched the net and forums but could not find any solutions for it. It seams some people had problems with it but no answers were posted on these questions.

here is my pom.xml with dependencies for testing:

```
{

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.client-drivers</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java-client-driver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.40.0</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.40.0</version>
    </dependency> 
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what error have you faced? please post your exception, your HTML snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now. I did not do any changes to my code. but i suspecting that me switching between different repositories and not rebuilding them fully caused problem when i tried to run my tests. So thank to everyone who looked and tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

For select lists you need to create the selenium select object.

```
WebElement we = find         element(by.cssSelector("whatever the select is"))
Select s = new Select(we);
s.selectByValue("value to select")
```

Pseudo code I didn't test it

Comment: Select does not work for p:selectOneMenu. I had like you said before but due to the spec change, we changed it to Primefaces p:selectOne and it needs to be done like i mentioned in my question.